# How to adjust the timestamp as per requirement

Tags: azure-logic-apps, x++, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

I am trying to generate the timestamp as per the requirement

The required format is : yyyy:mm:ddThh:mm:ssGMT+1:00

I am able to generate the Date and time format but unable to figure out how to bring out GMT+1:00
this format is required to send it to third party service.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is the time after GMT (+1:00) fixed?

Comment: "ShipTimestamp":"2020-10-15T12:30:47GMT+01:00" I am trying to generate like this

No, the datetime stamp that is mentioned should be in present and within 10 future days

Comment: "ShipTimestamp":"2020-10-15T12:30:47GMT+01:00" I am trying to generate like this

No, the datetime stamp that is mentioned should be in present and within 10 future days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, it's just a string so all you need to do is throw the `GMT+1:00` on the end.

[image: Flow]

Obviously, you need to get the correct date and time for your timezone but I've just thrown this expression in as a prefix for testing purposes ...

```
formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy:mm:ddThh:mm:ss')
```

##### Result

[image: Result]